# How can I solve these line errors on MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

As you can see, there's no syntax error or something like that on my code. Can you guys help me?

[image: Here an example...]

Comment: We can see the table `example` already exists..

Comment: Please read this guide on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: so there is no errors, you succeed to creata tha table. what your question is about?

Comment: I executed the command and the table was created, ok! But I have to execute commands one by one, because if I code more than one command it doesn't work....

Comment: Why the workbench is showing these red "X"?

Comment: Does it say anything if you hover the x?

Comment: Also, what version workbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is just a little bug in the error markup machinery. Try editing the code or close this editor and open a new one. If you have a list of steps to reproduce this you could even create a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com), so that gets fixed.

Comment: Well, I uninstall the version I had on my pc and install a previous, and it works for me, thank you guys anyway!

Comment: It's actually really easy to reproduce for me in the latest version of MySQL Workbench. Type any complete SQL statement (e.g. "SELECT * FROM table1;") and you'll see a red X symbol next to the statement like in the OP's picture above.

Comment: Seeing the same thing in MYSQL 5.7 Workbench...odd.

Comment: Same bug with my Workbench 6.3.7 - reported here https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82741

Comment: This has been fixed in 6.3.9.

Comment: I see the same error in mine. The code runs with no errors, but the editor shows line error x's. I am using Workbench 6.3.8.