# How do I solve the red X (error markers) in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

As shown in picture even if my Sql statement without error, but the Red Cross is still there.

[image]

Comment: Linking in a picture is bad form.

Comment: The first answer is my experiment.Because I'm a newcomer so my reputation is too low,I'm sorry I can't make my images show directly. i answer the question like this question Yesterday,the link is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125736/how-can-i-solve-these-line-errors-on-mysql-workbench/41158395#41158395),i post my answer.but The_so_called_celebrity vote against.I am a newcomer but I am a warm-hearted respondents.I don`t know why they even  have a good experiment before the vote!

Comment: This is actually a known bug. The error markers are not properly updated. This will be addressed in a future version of MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @ Mike Lischke  hope the best workbench would come as soon as possible!Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

After my experiment, I found the following steps can eradicate red fork.

first, write the right sql as usual,as you see,the red Cross still exists.

[image]

then format the sql,as you see,all goes well!

[image]

I wrote this quiz is the purpose of telling some so-called celebrity effect depend on ourselves to give positive respondents voted against the people!
You are a celebrity, but also please I hope you have a good experiment before the vote!